# Modify the dash in biblatex ibid

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}`

Is it possible to modify the dash used in the bibliography to denote the same author by another symbol (e.g. a much longer dash)? Something like `\renewcommand{\ibidendash}{\textemdash\textemdash}`? The documentation shows how to turn off dashes, but not to modify them.

An example is the `50-style-authoryear.tex` file.

[image]

Comment: The command is `\bibnamedash` and is defined in `biblatex.def` (and described in the manual). You can redefine it. But note that it is a more complicated macro than you might guess. If you are using a 'contributed' style, they might redefine it also, so you should check. You will also probably need to adjust the `\bibhang` length to accommodate the longer dash length. It is a length, so you `\setlength{\bibhang}{<length>}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version which uses a rule set to a fraction of the length of `\bibhang`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Chomsky1986,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Barriers},
    Year = {1986}}

@book{Chomsky1981,
    Address = {Dordrecht},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Foris Publications},
    Title = {Lectures on Government and Binding},
    Year = {1981}}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\setlength\bibhang{.5in}
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{0.75em}
    {\mbox{\textemdash\space}}
    {\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{%
       \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{1.25em}
         {\textendash}
         {\rule{.8\bibhang}{.2pt}}}}}
\begin{document}
\autocite{Chomsky1981,Chomsky1986}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

```
\setlength\bibhang{2.4em}%% two dashes and space
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\textemdash\textemdash\space}
```